# can we change servlet filter with in-it parameters as interceptor in spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc, interceptor

I have a filter in one of the jar files added as reference.

My project is in spring nature. I have developed a web services. All the requests to this web services should be intercepted by my filter "HelloWorld".

This filter is there in one of the reference files.

Here I thought I would implement it as Interceptor.

The filter in reference files looks like

```
public class HelloWorld implements Filter {
private static final Logger _logger = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class.getName());

  protected String name = null;

  public HelloWorld()
  {
  }

  public HelloWorld(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("Hello "+name);     
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {

        //Get init parameter
        String testParam = config.getInitParameter("test");

        //Print the init parameter
        System.out.println("test param: " + testParam);
    }
    public void destroy() {
        //add code to release any resource
    }

    //some other methods as well 
}
```

What would be the best way to implement this. I cannot configure filter in my web.xml due to limitation in my application.

Can we directly give this HelloWorld filter as reference to interceptor, so that it behaves like interceptor.
Can we change this filter as interceptor in spring and configure in spring.xml without changing the functionality.

Apologies if my question is simple.

Thanks.

Comment: *"due to limitation in my application"* which limitation exactly? If you're targeting a Servlet 3.0 compatible container, then you can also just use `@WebFilter` annotation.

Comment: @BalusC.I have to configure my filters as beans in my spring.xml only. I cannot configure it in web.xml. II thought this as limitataion.

Comment: To clear the understanding , so you want to re implement this filter into a Spring Interceptor ?

Comment: @Sudhakar. Yes. This filter is already present in one of the referenced files. I cannot change it. Can I use it like Interceptor.